# OpenGL pitching problem

Tags: opengl, camera, glut

I've been trying to implement several camera movements for my application. So far yawing, rolling, strafing, walking has been working properly, but I can't get my pitching to work properly. If I continue pitching upwards, it doesn't rotate back 360 degree, and instead gets stuck looking at the top of the screen.

Here's my code for `Camera` class

```
class Camera
{
    float m[16];
    Vector dirForward, dirUp, dirRight;

    void loadCameraDirections()
    {
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
        dirForward = Vector(m[2], m[6], m[10]).unitVector();
        dirUp = Vector(m[1], m[5], m[9]).unitVector();
        dirRight = Vector(m[0], m[4], m[8]).unitVector();
    }

public:
    Vector position;
    Vector lookAt;
    Vector up;

    Camera()
    {
        position = Vector(300, 0, 100);
        lookAt = Vector(0, 0, 100);
        up = Vector(0, 0, 1);
    }

    void rotatePitch(double rotationAngle)
    {
        glPushMatrix(); {
            glRotatef(rotationAngle, dirRight.x, dirRight.y, dirRight.z);
            loadCameraDirections();
        } glPopMatrix();

        lookAt = position.repositionBy(dirForward.reverseVector());
    }
}cam;
```

I call the `gluLookAt` funtion by-

```
gluLookAt(cam.position.x, cam.position.y, cam.position.z, cam.lookAt.x, cam.lookAt.y, cam.lookAt.z, cam.up.x, cam.up.y, cam.up.z);
```

Comment: why not use a math lib like glm to do the matrix math. It'll let you drop the deprecated calls.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. It was needed to update the `up` vector during pitching.

```
void rotatePitch(double rotationAngle)
{
    glPushMatrix(); {
        glRotatef(rotationAngle, dirRight.x, dirRight.y, dirRight.z);
        loadCameraDirections();
    } glPopMatrix();

    lookAt = position.repositionBy(dirForward.reverseVector());
    up = dirUp;
}
```

This solved the problem.